# Relativsatz mit mehreren Bezugswörtern mit unterschiedlichem Artikel

Tags: relative-clause, relative-pronoun

Wie wird ein Relativsatz gebildet, wenn dieser sich auf mehrere Bezugswörter mit verschiedenen Artikeln bezieht?

---

Hier ein Beispielsatz:

> Dies gilt generell für den Entwurf eines Diagramms oder einer Grafik, (das/die/welches/welche?) von vielen Personen verwendet wird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In der Duden-Grammatik (8./9. Auflage) heißt es dazu unter Randnummer 1594:

> Wenn zwischen den Substantiven ein alternatives Verhältnis besteht […] richtet sich das Pronomen nach dem zunächst stehenden Substantiv:
>
> > Das Buch oder die Schrift, die mein Interesse erregte, habe ich leider nicht erhalten.

Das ist mit meinem Sprachgefühl kompatibel. Demnach hieße es:

> Dies gilt generell für den Entwurf eines Diagramms oder einer Grafik, die von vielen Personen verwendet wird.

Answer (score 3):

Alle vier Optionen, regelkonform oder nicht, lösen beim Leser eine Zuordnungsirritation und grammatikalische Überlegungen aus, was grundsätzlich ungut ist. Der Leser sollte die Satzaussage möglichst reibungslos entgegennehmen. Im gegebenen Fall hilft eine einfache Umformulierung:

> Dies gilt generell für den Entwurf von Diagrammen oder Grafiken,
> die von vielen Personen verwendet werden.

Answer (score 1):

Nehmen wir für einen Moment an, statt dem "oder" stünde dort ein "und":

> Dies gilt generell für den Entwurf eines Diagramms *und* einer Grafik, (das/die/welches/welche?)

In diesem Fall wäre klar, daß wir den Plural verwenden müßten, denn "Diagramm und Graphik" sind zwei. Der Satz müßte also lauten:

> Dies gilt generell für den Entwurf eines Diagramms *und* einer Grafik, *welche* von vielen Personen verwendet *werden*.

Was für "und" gilt, gilt auch für "oder": der Relativsatz bezieht sich nicht auf das eine *oder* das andere, sondern auf die gesamte Gruppe "eine Graphik oder ein Diagramm" und diese Gruppe erfordert den Plural.

> Dies gilt generell für den Entwurf eines Diagramms *oder* einer Grafik, *welche* von vielen Personen verwendet *werden*.